# node-postgres : query not executing in sequence

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

i have kept insert & update code in 2 different files and based on condition 
always insert should execute first and then update.**but somehow update executes first then insert**

### test.js  : simplified code

i am using these packages  :[pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) , [uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid)

```
var pg = require('pg');
var uuid = require('node-uuid').v4;
var id = uuid().toString();
var conString = 'postgres://postgres:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/testdb';

// ------INSERT
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {

    console.log('Executing Insert query');

    client.query('insert into testdb (id,data,iscancelled) values ($1,$2,$3)',[id,'hello','no'],  function(err, result) {

        done();

        if(err) { return console.error('error running query', err);  }

        console.log('finished executing Insert query');

    });
});

// ------UPDATE
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {

    console.log('Executing update query');

    client.query("update testdb set iscancelled = 'yes' where id = $1",[id],  function(err, result) {

        done();

        if(err) { return console.error('error running query', err);  }

        console.log('finished executing Update query');

    });
});
```

### output

```
tom@tom:~$node test.js
Executing Insert query
Executing update query
finished executing Update query //WHY UPDATE FINISHES FIRST
finished executing Insert query
```

### Note :

this problem can be easily solved by using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).But my insert code and update code are in different files and depending on some situation update code might execute.so don't want to use async

### Problem

Even though Insert query goes to execute first **why does update finishes first in output**

am i missing any thing ..?

Comment: What do you mean by "my insert code and update code are in different files"? Are they included one in another?  Separating code into files doesn't change asynchronous principles. Your update function should be in the insert callback if you want to ensure consistency.

Comment: they are not included in one another just firing insert first then update...and not depended on each other according to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Lets solve this question step by step**

you "s*tated so don't want to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)*" libraries

**solution 1 :**

if PostgreSQL make update faster, update will return result before insert. If you want start executing update query only after finishing insert then

[you should set connection pool capacity to 1.](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/pg#connectstring-connectionstring-function-callback)

```
pg.defaults.poolSize = 1
```

but you should do this before any `pg.connect()`

The connect method retrieves a Client from the client pool, or if all pooled clients are busy and the pool is not full, the connect method will create a new client passing its first argument directly to the Client constructor. In either case, your supplied callback will only be called when the Client is ready to issue queries or an error is encountered. The callback will be called once and only once for each invocation of connect.

**Conclusion** : your queries will execute in sequence.**BUT BUT BUT** this solution is **BAD** for scaling app as there will be always only one connection serving all users .So till one connection is serving one user , other users will have to wait for response.

**Solution 2 :**

you also stated "*i have kept insert & update code in 2 different files*"

it looks like you need to designed your code in such a way that it you are able to use [asynchronus](https://github.com/caolan/async) libraries , that solves this problem

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned, the only way to ensure that *update* function will be fired only after *insert* function is done, is to call it inside of  *insert* function callback. That are the basics of [asynchronous programming](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_async.html).

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {

    console.log('Executing Insert query');

    client.query('insert into testdb (id,data,iscancelled) values ($1,$2,$3)',[id,'hello','no'],  function(err, result) {

        done();

        if(err) { return console.error('error running query', err);  }

        console.log('finished executing Insert query');

        // ------UPDATE
        pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {

            console.log('Executing update query');

            client.query("update testdb set iscancelled = 'yes' where id = $1",[id],  function(err, result) {

            done();

            if(err) { return console.error('error running query', err);  }

            console.log('finished executing Update query');

        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the asynchronous nature of the pg.connect and also client.query. The call to these return a callback which passes the control to next expression before the completion of execution and hence non-blocking nature of nodejs. If you want to assure the correct flow, either call the successive ones inside the callback success

```
var pg = require('pg');
var uuid = require('node-uuid').v4;
var id = uuid().toString();

// ------INSERT
return pg.connect;

// ------UPDATE
return pg.connect;

// your calling file
var insert = require('/path/to/insertfile');
var conString = 'postgres://postgres:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/testdb';
var update = require('/path/to/updatefile');

insert(conString, function (err, client, done) {
    console.log('Executing Insert query');
    client.query('insert into testdb (id,data,iscancelled) values ($1,$2,$3)',[id,'hello','no'],  function (err, result) {
        if (err) { 
           return console.error('error running query', err);  
        }
        console.log('finished executing Insert query');

        update(conString, function (error, client, done) {
           console.log('Executing update query');

           client.query("update testdb set iscancelled = 'yes' where id = $1",[id],  function (err, result) {

              if (err) { 
                  return console.error('error running query', err);  
              }
              console.log('finished executing Update query');
              done();
          });
        });
        done();
    });    

});
```

But this is very prone to callback hell. So consider making all async call return a promise. Take a look at [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). If you want an ORM that has built in promise based call, you can take a look at [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/). It might be handy for you.

It has syntax as easy as:

```
var Model1 = require('/path/to/model1');
var Model2 = require('/path/to/model2');

var insertObj = {
    "someKey": "value"
};

Model1.create(insertObj)
     .then( function (createdObj1) {
         return Model2.findOne({
             where: {
                "filter": "filterValue"
             }
         });
     })
     .then( function (documentToUpdate) {
         return documentToUpdate.update({
             "fieldToUpdate": "value"
         });  
     })
     .then( null, function (err) {
         console.log(err);
     });
```

Comment: Also, there is `pg-promise` module, https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise.  Might help you!

Comment: @plutopunch if people are helping you and you find the answer helpful, have a habit of upvoting the answer and selecting the suitable answer.

Comment: @Pravin your answer shows asynchronus behaviour..where as i have stated in question i don't want to use async